# What is the affected space for the area of Burning Hands?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

*Burning hands* states:

> As you hold your hands with thumbs touching and fingers spread, a thin sheet of flames shoots forth from your outstretched fingertips.

However, it goes on to affect a cone with a 15 foot diameter base (which is certainly not a thin sheet).

> Each creature in a 15-foot cone must make a Dexterity saving throw

**What area can actually affect creatures, the thin sheet or the cone? Is it different for objects?**

> The fire ignites any flammable objects in the area that aren't being worn or carried.

*For a use case: Does a tiny creature flying 10 feet away and 10 feet in the air get hit by the 5 foot tall caster's straight burning hands? Does the carpet below catch fire?*